# Reduce downloading data size of multiple json links

Tags: android, json, web

I have a few http links. One of them is for example this one:

https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker

It's size is actually **188 B** but when I take a look into data consumption of my app, which is downloading this url, it shows me **3 kB**. I am using OkHTTPClient from Otto Square. It looks something like:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            client.setReadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(new URL(url));
                in = connection.getInputStream();
                byte[] response = readFully(in);
                return new String(response, "UTF-8");
                } catch (Exception e){}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to reduce downloading size of that to the minimum without any extra app for this purpose? I also tried to use simple DefaultHTTPClient, HTTPUrlConnection and maybe the others (but actually, I don't remember). Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The size of an HTTP (or for that matter, any protocol) request depends on a few factors. The [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) or the size of a single packet, the number of packets used by the request which in turn is determined by the contents of the request which includes the [protocol overhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_overhead).

From your question, if a packet size of 1500 is assumed, the request seems to be using 2 packets. If you have followed the above links, it might be clear to you that the least you can make a request is 1 packet, which, most likely takes up 1500 bytes. Google has some suggestions to [minimize request overhead](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request) that is applicable to any HTTP request, not just for Android.